# remove gnupg V.2.1.15 and libgcrypt V.1.7.8 then install gnupg V.2.1.0 and libgcrypt V.1.6.3

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg, libgcrypt, gpg-agent

I use Lubuntu V.17.10 on my laptop. on this version of Lubuntu installed by default  gnupg V.2.1.15 and libgcrypt V.1.7.8.
I want to remove gnupg V.2.1.15 and libgcrypt V.1.7.8 then install gnupg V.2.1.0 and libgcrypt V.1.6.3.
In the past, I installed  gnupg V.2.1.0 and libgcrypt V.1.6.3. But when I use the multi command I give conflict answers.

```
~$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.15
libgcrypt 1.7.8
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Home: /home/baudline/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2



~$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.0
libgcrypt 1.7.8
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed



~$libgcrypt-config --version
1.6.3
```

These conflicts cause I am not confident about installing gnupg V.2.1.0 and libgcrypt V.1.6.3. 
I want when I use the command `gpg --version` I give these answer`gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.0`  `libgcrypt 1.6.3`

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question. It would probably be on topic at [ubuntu.se], [unix.se] or [su]